# Windows Mobile (C# code) - cannot download data from the Web when the device is connected to the PC

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I develop an app which downloades a file from the Internet (over WiFi). The problem is when I connect to the WiFi network and then I connect my phone to the PC (to debug the code on the device) I cannot download any data from the web. If I disconnect the device from the PC everything works fine. Anyone knows what may causes the problem ?

Comment: I do this type of debugging all the time - it's how I develop and test my asynchronous socket code between the handset and the server (using Wi-Fi).  Can you share some info on which version of VS you're using, the handset and its specs, etc., etc.?  You should also be able to setup a SystemState listener to determine which connections you have (Actiive Synch, Wi-Fi, or cellular) to see if for some strange reason you're losing your Wi-Fi when ActiveSync kicks in (might have to write that to a Log txt file on the handset).

Answer (score 2):

On some devices, the WiFi drivers are [disabled](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=1822494&prodTypeId=215348&objectID=c01079047) when the device is connected via ActiveSync. You can tell if yours is doing this by going to the Wireless Center and checking the state of your 802.11 WiFi radio.

You can get around this by having a thread in your application listen for `NDISUIO_NOTIFICATION_DEVICE_POWER_DOWN` events and then issuing a `SetDevicePower( ..., D0 );` to re-enable the radio as soon as it is disabled.

-PaulH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the network that is used is changed when you connect to the PC.